# How to parallelize requests in MVC6 on a per action basis

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm wondering how to parallelize requests with the upcomming MVC 6. (Since unless you do some extra work, ASP will synchronize requests up until 5.2.2).

In the past you could do so using [SessionState(Readonly)] on a controller which i planned on contributing a per action version.

I've cloned the mvc project and it seems like there is no such attribute anymore? Judging by docs i've run into it appears, in order to even get a session you have to call a method first during configuration.

Does this mean that all requests are now potentially parallel by default or is this a missconception? Also if enabling the session is done globally per configuration is there a built in version to allow parallel execution on a per action basis or will i need my session middleware to control that behavior?

I'd test it myself, but unfortunately my solution won't compile because of a dnx core 5.0 problem.

Does anyone have information on this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe MVC 6 has session state any longer which the reason for that issue. There is an optional session middleware `Microsoft.AspNet.Session` that has to be installed separately, if that feature is needed.